# Java pattern to match ; while skipping it in &amp;

Tags: java, regex

Is there pattern in Java regex to match ; while skipping &amp; like texts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the regex like :  `(?<!&amp);`  [Demo and Exaplaination](https://regex101.com/r/eE3cG3/2)

meaning of regex : find the  **;** which is not preceeded by **&amp**

Code sample :

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!&amp);");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("; abd &amp; this is what ;");
while(matcher.find()){
    System.out.println("find start position "+matcher.start() +" find end position "+matcher.end()+" find for "+ matcher.group(0)); 
}
```

> O/P
>
> find start position 0 find end position 1 find for ;
>
> find start position 25 find end position 26 find for ;

Comment: That worked; Thanks heaps. See it in action at http://ideone.com/Ml2lF6.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for a regex like the following:

> ^(?!.*&).*;.*$

```
String line = "&abc\;";

Pattern r = Pattern.compile("^(?!.*&).*;.*$");
Matcher m = r.matcher(line);
if (m.find( )) 
System.out.println("Match found");
```